# Fourier transform of $\phi$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, klein-gordon-equation

I was reading through [David Tong's Lectures Notes on Quantum Field Theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html) and I was wondering how, on page 22, he derives that the Fourier transform of $\phi(\vec{x}, t), \tilde{\phi}(\vec{p}, t)$, satisfies
$$
\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}+\omega_{\vec{p}}^2\right) \tilde{\phi}(\vec{p}, t)=0,\tag{2.6}
$$
where $$\omega_{\vec{p}} \equiv \sqrt{\vec{p}^2+m^2},\tag{2.7}$$ and $$\phi(\vec{x}, t)=\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2 \pi)^3} \tilde{\phi}(\vec{p}, t) e^{i \vec{x} \cdot \vec{p}}, \quad \tilde{\phi}(\vec{p}, t)=\int d^3 x \phi(\vec{x}, t) e^{-i \vec{x} \cdot \vec{p}}.\tag{2.5}$$ How can this be shown to be true?

Comment: Take the (3D) FT of the EOM of $\phi$... or just plug your expression for $\tilde \phi$ into the differential equation.

Comment: If you haven't already, you should review what happens when [you take the derivative of a Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Differentiation).

Comment: *"How can this be shown to be true?"* It is shown via a perfectly straightforward and ordinary application of the Fourier transform to both sides of the equation...

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively easy to do. Simply Fourier expand the Klein Gordon equation, i.e. take the Fourier transform of the entire Klein-Gordon equation:
$$\mathcal F[\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\phi]-\mathcal F[m^2\phi]=0.$$ The transforms are not terribly difficult to workout in this case, however, they can be easily done using a table of Fourier transforms like that found in a CRC handbook of mathematical tables and formulae. At any rate, lets take a look at some of the basic issues.

We can write the above transformation of the Klein-Gordon equation as:
$$\mathcal F[{\partial^2\phi\over\partial t^2}-\nabla^2\phi]-\mathcal F[m^2\phi]=0,$$ using the *linearity property* of the Fourier transform we get:
$$\mathcal F[{\partial^2\phi\over\partial t^2}]-\mathcal F[\nabla^2\phi]-m^2\mathcal F[\phi]=0.$$
Since time is not a variable of integration in the transform, we can remove the temporal derivative out from under the integral sign:
$${\partial^2\over\partial t^2}\mathcal F[\phi]-\mathcal F[\nabla^2\phi]-m^2\mathcal F[\phi]=0.$$
Thus,
$$\bigg({\partial^2\over\partial t^2}-m^2\bigg)\mathcal F[\phi]-\mathcal F[\nabla^2\phi]=0.$$
So the next big question is what to do with the term containing the spatial derivatives. Here we can use a standard formula, which easily provable by direct computation:
$$\mathcal F\bigg[{d^n\over dx^n}f(x)\bigg]=(i|\vec p|)^n F(\vec p),$$
where $F(\vec p)$ is the Fourier transform of the function $f(x)$. So applying this *differentiation property* we get:
$$\mathcal F\bigg[\nabla^2\phi\bigg]=-|\vec p|^2 \mathcal F[\phi].$$
Plugging this into our equation for the transformed klein-Gordon equation we get:
$$\bigg({\partial^2\over\partial t^2}+|\vec p|^2-m^2\bigg)\mathcal F[\phi]=0.$$
This is the sought after relation where of course, $\mathcal F[\phi(\vec x,t)]=\phi(\vec p,t)$.